# Retrieve the data from one component to another

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, angular-routing

We are trying to use the NavigationExtras to pass data from one component to another (one page to another) like below

```
      viewProjectDetails(e) {
        const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
            state: {
              ProjectInfo: e.data,
              UserSelection: this.UserSelection
            }
        };
        this.router.navigate(['dashboard/ProjectShipment'], navigationExtras);
    }
```

I am trying to get the `ProjectInfo` and `UserSelection` array in to the another component

```
projDetail : any;
userSelection: any;

getPrjDetails() {    
    const navigation = this.activatedRoute.getCurrentNavigation();
    const state = navigation.extras.state as {
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen to the queryParams and catch the NavigationExtras

```
 this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params["state"]); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
           console.log(this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.Projectinfo); 
 // should log e.data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `getCurrentNavigation()` method inside of the constructor, elsewhere the navigation has finished.